# Lightweight, safe way to parse an int or float (ocaml)

Tags: ocaml

I have been using Int.of_string, but I'm wondering what the lightest dependency footprint way of parsing an int, float, or other primitive types from a string, that returns a Result or similar type, rather than an exception, when the string is not a proper value?

My first guess is a parser combinator library. Is there anything within a standard library  like Base or Core that provides very simple parser combinator functionality? If not, would you go with angstrom?

Comment: I noticed Or_error.try_with for wrapping exception throwing functions. That looks okay, but seems a little ugly to throw and catch exception, leaning towards angstrom

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like:

```
# Scanf.sscanf "123abc" "%d" (fun x -> x);;
- : int = 123
```

Scanf simply stops when the input stops making sense for the format you request. But it still throws an exception if the input is totaly incomprehensible, e.g.:

```
# Scanf.sscanf "abc" "%d" (fun x -> x);;
Exception:
Scanf.Scan_failure
 "scanf: bad input at char number 0: character 'a' is not a decimal digit".
```

Comment: If sscanf returned a Result instead, this would work for me. I want to avoid wrapping code that throws exceptions. I will look around to see if anybody has implemented alternatives versions of sscanf